# How to Embed 2 or more Power BI reports in a Single web page?

Tags: powerbi, embedding

I have a standard user owns sample application which can embed 1 report at a time, however, I need to embed 2 or more reports in a single web page. If there is a sample solution file that can do this Job, that's great.

Answer (score 1):

To [embed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embed-report) Power BI element using the JavaScript client, you must [configure the settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings) (which report/dashboard/tile to be embedded, how to authorize the request, what view mode, provide additional filters, etc.) and then call the `embed` method passing the configuration and a `<div>` element where the embedded element will be loaded.

This code is from the sample:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
// Licensed under the MIT license.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$(function () {
    var models = window["powerbi-client"].models;
    var reportContainer = $("#report-container").get(0);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/embedinfo/getembedinfo",
        success: function (data) {
            embedParams = $.parseJSON(data);
            reportLoadConfig = {
                type: "report",
                tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
                accessToken: embedParams.EmbedToken.Token,
                // You can embed different reports as per your need
                embedUrl: embedParams.EmbedReport[0].EmbedUrl,

                // Enable this setting to remove gray shoulders from embedded report
                // settings: {
                //     background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent
                // }
            };

            // Use the token expiry to regenerate Embed token for seamless end user experience
            // Refer https://aka.ms/RefreshEmbedToken
            tokenExpiry = embedParams.EmbedToken.Expiration;

            // Embed Power BI report when Access token and Embed URL are available
            var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, reportLoadConfig);

            // Clear any other loaded handler events
            report.off("loaded");

            // Triggers when a report schema is successfully loaded
            report.on("loaded", function () {
                console.log("Report load successful");
            });

            // Clear any other rendered handler events
            report.off("rendered");

            // Triggers when a report is successfully embedded in UI
            report.on("rendered", function () {
                console.log("Report render successful");
            });

            // Clear any other error handler events
            report.off("error");
            
            // Handle embed errors
            report.on("error", function (event) {
                var errorMsg = event.detail;
            
                // Use errorMsg variable to log error in any destination of choice
                console.error(errorMsg);
                return;
            });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            
            // Show error container
            var errorContainer = $(".error-container");
            $(".embed-container").hide();
            errorContainer.show();
            
            // Format error message
            var errMessageHtml = "<strong> Error Details: </strong> <br/>" + err.responseText;
            errMessageHtml = errMessageHtml.split("\n").join("<br/>");

            // Show error message on UI
            errorContainer.append(errMessageHtml);
        }
    });
});
```

So to be able to embed multiple elements, you must prepare multiple configurations (see `reportLoadConfig` in the sample code), prepare multiple placeholders (see `reportContainer` in the sample code) and call `powerbi.embed` multiple times.

Check again this article - [Understanding the different embedding solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embedding-solutions). For your tests you can use the [developer sandbox](https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/) in the Power BI playground.